# Powershell script to return only totalitems from and exchange 2003 mailbox

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm working on a Powershell script that will return only the total items from and Exchange 2003 mailbox. So far I have this:

> get-wmiobject -computername exchange01 -namespace root\microsoftexchangev2 -class exchange_mailbox -filter "mailboxdisplayname='Journal Mail'" | select-object totalitems | write-host

However this give the results as:

> @{totalitems=939}

I only want the number to be returned as we have an external program that will read this number and send a notification if it exceeds a predetermined number.

I'm having trouble finding a way to strip out all the unnecessary information from the results. Any suggestions are welcome to how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Select-Object returns an object with one property, assign the result to a variable and refer to the property name:

```
$mbx = get-wmiobject -computername exchange01 -namespace root\microsoftexchangev2 -class exchange_mailbox -filter "mailboxdisplayname='Journal Mail'" 
$mbx.totalitems
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```
get-wmiobject -computername exchange01 -namespace root\microsoftexchangev2 -class exchange_mailbox -filter "mailboxdisplayname='Journal Mail'" | select-object -ExpandProperty totalitems
```